# How to convert list of digits to number?

Tags: functions, number-representation

I have a list such as:

```
a = {1, 2, 4, 3};
```

and I want to get the 'number' of the list. For this example, I want to get this number: `1243`. I do not know how to get it easily. For now, my solution is:
    `a[[1]]*10^3+a[[2]]*10^2+a[[3]]*10^1+a[[4]];`
It works. But it is too complex. I want to know a way more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {1, 2, 4, 3};
FromDigits[a]

(* 1243 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Other than the built-in `FromDigits`, we can build our wheel

```
Fold[{10, 1}.{##} &, a]
```

Comment: I want to know what is the mean of 'wheel'. Is it a function to achieve something? I know what you express, but I am interest in the meaning of 'wheel'.

Comment: @user61054 Do you want to know what the figurative meaning of "wheel" or how the function `Fold` works?

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to use build-in function `FromDigits` as shown above.

But just in case you'd like a convoluted way to do it, here is another option

```
a = {1, 2, 4, 3};
ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[#] & /@ a]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

These are some methods I would **not** recommend:

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4};

f = (Curry[StringRiffle][""] /* ToExpression);

g = (Through[{
    Identity,
    Length /* Range /* Reverse /* Curry[Plus][-1] /* Curry[Power, 2][10]
}[#]] & /* MapThread[Times] /* Total);

f[lst] (* 1234 *)
g[lst] (* 1234 *)
```

Comment: Are you really serious that you would not recommend this? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that is faster than `FromDigits` for the construction of *many* numbers at once:

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1000000, 10}];
r1 = FromDigits /@ a; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = FromDigits[Transpose[a]]; // RepeatedTiming
r3 = a.(10^Range[9, 0, -1]); // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 == r2 == r3
```

> 0.466
>
> 0.068
>
> 0.040
>
> True

Admittedly, `FromDigits[Transpose[a]]` is only slower than `a.(10^Range[9, 0, -1])` because of `Transpose`.